# How to debug Electron.JS when there's no any error messages?

Tags: electron

Quite frequently you break something in your app and the Electron.JS displays just a blank screen with absolutely no information about the error.

The dev tools are blank too.

How to debug it? I found so far only one solution - you start commenting out code randomly until the app again start working an so you can guess what caused the error.

[image]

Comment: Fwiw - I've been using `Electron` for 2-3 years now and have very rarely had that sort of "DevTools disconnected" error. More context is needed.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't any secret debugging method that can help aside from what you mentioned in your post about randomly commenting out code. As for your specific problem I agree with @NoGrabbing that there isn't enough infomation. If you can include the specific code that causes the dev tools error then we can help.